# Mutation returns 400 error but works in GraphiQL

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, express-graphql

I've been following tutorials and trying to learn graphql with react and express and I'm running into trouble. My mutation works when I plug it into graphiql but not when I call it from my client.

**Client code:**

```
async addBook(params) {
    var title = params["title"];
    var author = params["author"];
    var src = params["src"];

    var mutation = `
        { addBook($author: String!, $title: String!, $src: String!) {
            addBook(author: $author, title: $title, src: $src) {
                id
                title
            }
        } 
    }`;

    const res = await fetch(this.apiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: mutation,
            variables: {author: author, title: title, src: src}
        }),
    });
    if (res.ok) {
        const body = await res.json();
        console.log(body.data);
        return body.data;
    } else {
        throw new Error(res.status);
    }
}
```

**Schema code:**

```
const typeDefs = `
    type Book {
        id: ID!
        author: String!
        title: String!
        src: String!

    }

    type Query {
        Books: [Book]
    }

    type Mutation {
        addBook(author: String, title: String, src: String): Book
    }
`;
```

**Resolver**

```
Mutation: {
    addBook: (root, args) => {
        const newBook = {id: Books.length+1, author: args.author, title: args.title, src: args.src};
        Books.push(newBook);
        return newBook;
    },
},
```

**The error**

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error GraphQL request (2:25) Expected Name, found $\n\n1: \n2:             { mutation ($author: String!, $title: String!, $src: String!) {\n                           ^\n3:                 addBook(author: $author, title: $title, src: $src) {\n","locations":[{"line":2,"column":25}]}]}
```

My "database" is a .js file containing a const *books*

I can send queries and get results but mutations seem to be harder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you paste the exact message being returned from the 400 error? you probably are getting a useful error message in the terminal of your express server

Comment: I've updated the question with the full error. I find it weird that this error does not appear in GraphiQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

graphiql's probably being forgiving with your syntax, but it doesn't look quite correct to me. I would expect something like this:

```
var mutation = `
    mutation AddBook($author: String!, $title: String!, $src: String!) {
        addBook(author: $author, title: $title, src: $src) {
            id
            title
        }
    } 
`;
```